# How to cache cordova's platform projects to prevent remote downloads when running "cordova platform add <platform>"?

Tags: cordova

Every time I run Cordova platform add , cordova fetches the cordova files for the specified platform from the internet. Is it possible to download those files to a local directory and force cordova to use them instead of the remote ones? Maybe there's a magical Env variable?

Comment: no,not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the platform locally from github and add it from the path instead of adding it from npm/github, but you can't use

```
cordova platform add <platform>
```

You will have to add it like

```
cordova platform add /path/to/platform/
```

Comment: just a few more variants

`cordova platform add cordova-android@~{version}` and

`cordova platform add cordova-ios@~{version}`

Comment: That will download it from the internet, the idea is to use a local copy. For adding an older version from the local copy, if it’s a github clone you just need to checkout the branch of the version you want

Comment: You are right. I just decided to put it in here in case someone falls upon this answer. At least that person will now that more variants of the command are supports and one of them is to point to specific remote version of each cordova's platform.

Comment: By the way I don't know if it's me but everytime I setup a platform using my local cordova platform, the `cordova_plugins` directory is not created at `/platforms/{the_platform}/platform_www` which will then break the app as plugins will not be available at runtime.

Comment: I have not noticed it, but looks like a bug. I only use local platforms when making changes in them, so usually don’t add plugins

Answer (score 0):

I know this is out of the scope of my question but I still think it's worth posting it as it might be useful to someone else.

The instructions bellow explain how to setup your local/offline cordova environment. This will save your time specially If you, just like me, have many apps to build and deploy to different platforms. As a bonus I also explain how to setup a local gradle which for android is the task that takes more time .

```
mkdir local_cordova && cd local_cordova && npm init
# confirm all stuff 
npm install cordova-fetch 
touch download-cordova-ios.js 
touch download-cordova-android.js 
open download-cordova-ios.js
# paste the lines below:   

var fetch = require('cordova-fetch'); 
var spec = 'cordova-ios@~4.5.1'; 
/* Version can be ommited */  
var dest = './bin/ios' 
var opts = { save: true } fetch(spec, dest, opts);

# save the file open download-cordova-android.js
# paste the lines below

# Now open the android file and do the same
open download-cordova-android.js


var fetch = require('cordova-fetch'); 
var spec = 'cordova-android@~6.3.0';
/* Version can be ommited */  
var dest = './bin/android' 
var opts = { save: true } 
fetch(spec, dest, opts);


# Now run the node command and wait for the script to complete
node download-cordova-android.js && node download-cordova-ios.js

# Now lets create some environment variables for each our local cordova platforms.
vim ~/.bash_profile
# add the following lines 
export CORDOVA_DROID="/path/to/your/cordova/cordova-fetch/bin/android/node_modules/cordova-android"; 

export CORDOVA_IOS="/path/to/your/cordova/cordova-fetch/bin/ios/node_modules/cordova-ios";

source ~/.bash_profile 

cd ~/Desktop/ 
cordova create test-app com.test.app test-app && cd test-app 
cordova platform add $CORDOVA_DROID 
cordova platform add $CORDOVA_IOS

cordova build android
#In a normal situation cordova will download a gradle which is 60+MB. Since this operation can take a while I suggest you to setup an environment variable that will save you lots of time.

# Go to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/
# and find the distribution that fits your needs
# mine was gradle-4.0.2-all.zip
# download it and place it somewhere in your disk. Consider a location that can be persisted over time.


vim ~/.bash_profile 
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=file:///path/to/your/gradle-4.0-all.zip

# That's all
```